# How to change text of text view or hide textview using accessibility?

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, accessibility

I want to either hide the text view of another app or want to change one of the text view of other app using accessibility service. I can get AccessibilityNodeInfo of text. How can I proceed next?

Answer (score 0):

Changing any property in AccessibilityNodeInfo is not good even in your own application.
Accessibility Technologies like TalkBack uses the values/data provided by the Accessibility Service(through Accessibility Node Info) to announce how the view/element looks like for the blind/partially blind users. Any usage of data that is received from the service to change the content even if possible is not good.

There are certain methods provided in the Accessibility Delegate to change how the text is being announced of a particular view but they should be used in a very specific scenario or particularly when there is some sort of shortcoming in the data provided by the Accessibility Service.